# Como reinstalar dotnet cli

Tags: windows10, .net-core, dotnetcore

Estoy con el SO Windows 10
Después de intentar desinstalar las versiones antiguas del skd de .NET Core (de la 3.1 hacia atrás) utilizando la herramienta: dotnet-core-uninstall me ha dejado de funcionar la cli de dotnet.
Al usar el comando obtengo el mensaje: "dotnet" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo
He reinstalado el sdk de netcore 6 pero sigue igual.
¿cómo puedo hacer para recuperarlo?

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido solucionarlo. Lo indico aquí por si a alguien más le sirve.
Lo que he hecho es reinstalar la última versión del SDK de NET Core 6.0.x y después volver a lanzar el instalador y seleccionar "Reparar".